# Unresolved sibling dependency when building one module

Tags: maven-3

I have a maven multi-module project whose parent POM states:

```
<modules>
  <module>ui</module>
  <module>controller</module>  <!-- Depends on ui module -->
</modules>
```

The following runs fine:

```
project-root> mvn clean package
```

However problems arise if I try:

```
project-root/controller> mvn clean package
```

The error reports the `ui` artifact as an unresolved dependency.

Yes, I realize that this question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677473/maven-doesnt-recognize-sibling-modules-when-running-mvn-dependencytree).  However it has no clear answer (the accepted answer for *that instance* is only a workaround).  This behavior is explained away as a difference between dependency resolution and reactor builds.  [A post about Maven 3](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2010/12/whats-in-maven-3-0-for-users/) suggests that it is resolved in that released.  I am using Maven 3.0.3 and see no relief.  [Maven 3.0.4's release notes](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.0.4/release-notes.html#Maven_3.0.4_Release_Notes) don't suggest a change in this behavior.

How do you handle such a situation? Is the only recourse to do a build from the `project-root` every time?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are faced with is that you try to call a build from a sibling, in which case the dependency resolution will be done against your local repository.

There are several solutions to your problem. The first one is to go to your root and do a `mvn install`.  Afterwards, you should be able to go to your controller and do `mvn clean package`.  But I recommend to *go to your root* and build specifically the controller module:

```
mvn -pl controller clean package
```

But the prerequisite is to do an mvn install before that.

Comment: As you will note from my question, I am aware of the `mvn install` first *workaround*.  Ideally I would like to be able to simply `mvn clean package` at `ui` module followed by `mvn clean package` at the `controller` module.

Comment: You can also check if -am helps better ? mvn -am -pl controller clean package ?

Comment: Using the `-am` switch results in all required modules (`ui` in my case) being (unnecessarily) rebuilt every time `controller` is built.  Yes, I even tried without running the `clean` phase.