# Maven multimodule project tries to download inner dependency from repository

Tags: java, maven, multi-module

I have a classical multimodule project with cross dependency

parent pom:

```
<modules>
    <module>mod1</module>
    <module>mod2</module>
</modules>
...
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>grp</groupId>
            <artifactId>mod1</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
...
```

mod2 pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>grp</groupId>
      <artifactId>mod1</artifactId>
    </dependency>
 ...
```

It builds `mvn clean install` fine, however when CI runs sonar using `mvn sonar:sonar ...` the maven tries to download `mod1` snapshot dependency from repo, which supposed to be part of the same reactor.

```
Downloading from nexus: http://...mod1/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
```

And it most cases it could not find the snapshot as it was not deployed yet, but it just keeps going. However it slows down the build as I have several modules and each takes a while to make a roundtrip to repository.

Why?

Answer (score -1):

I had a very similar problem: `mvn install` was working fine, `mvn sonar:sonar` wasn't.

In my case, it was a test dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>grp</groupId>
  <artifactId>mod2</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

It was solved by adding `test-compile` to the `mvn` command:

```
mvn test-compile sonar:sonar
```

I got the tip from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57226037/5269825

I guess maven needs something (like `compile` or `compile-test`) to know that the dependency is another submodule.

Comment: That sounds like you had `maven.test.skip` set during your build.  I run `mvn sonar:sonar` alone without issues after having separately built the code, using just such a test jar dependency.